# Question about compiling from ruby source and upgrade

Tags: upgrade, compiling, ruby, make

I have three questions about compiling ruby (and other softwares) from source. Ruby is avaliable to install using apt-get, but I want to learn more about Linux and I want to compile from source.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I first downloaded ruby source from [ruby site](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and extracted in my home: `/home/rgiaviti/ruby-2.1.2`. Then, I opened terminal and typed:

```
rgiaviti@ubuntupc:~$ cd /home/ruby-2.1.2
rgiaviti@ubuntupc:~/ruby-2.1.2$ ./configure
rgiaviti@ubuntupc:~/ruby-2.1.2$ make
rgiaviti@ubuntupc:~/ruby-2.1.2$ sudo make install
```

After a lot of output, everything worked fine. Absolutely fine. I tested ruby interpreter this way:

```
ruby --version
```

Output:

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

Success, right? Now, my questions:

1. When a new ruby interpreter is released, how do I upgrade my installed version? Just do the same thing I do when installing?
2. Can I delete the folder that I extracted the source (`/home/rgiaviti/ruby-2.1.2`)?
3. Is there a way to uninstall the interpreter, like a `apt-get remove`, but for compiling from source?

I think, that's all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a new ruby interpreter is released, how do I upgrade my installed version? Just do the same thing I do when installing?

Probably, presuming that new versions don't change paths. This is fairly unlikely to break updated installs, but might leave detritus littered around your system.

> Can I delete the folder that I extracted the source (/home/rgiaviti/ruby-2.1.2)?

Yes. After `install`, this is no longer needed.

> Is there a way to uninstall the interpreter, like a apt-get remove, but for compiling from source?

No! Personally, I would never directly install from source. As I mention above, this often results in files littered through your system. In the future, I would recommend using [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall), which rolls your install into a package for easy management.